# Trouble posting image file from Android app to Java servlet hosted on Tomcat

Tags: java, android, servlets, file-upload, http-post

One feature of an Android app I am working on is to take a picture and upload it via HTTP Post to a Java servlet. I have found a number of examples of how the general process should work, and tried all of them. Currently, the code looks like this:

Client:

```
String fileName = pathToFile;
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost method = new HttpPost(path);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(fileName));
entity.addPart("file", fileBody);
method.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
```

Server:

```
List<FileItem> fileItems =
new ServletFileUpload( new DiskFileItemFactory( 1024 * 1024, new File("C:\\tmp" ))).
parseRequest(request);

for ( FileItem item : fileItems ) {
String fieldName = item.getFieldName();

if ( item.isFormField()) { 
    item.getString();
}
else {
    item.getInputStream();
} // File uploaded
}
```

Right now, I am not worried about what to do with the input stream, because this code fails when we call parseRequest(request) with this error:
`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly`

I am a new user of the Apache HttpUpload library. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know which side is having the problem?  Can you upload images through your servlet from a regular web form?

Comment: Good question. I just tested this with a simple HTML form and it worked perfectly... All I did was add some code to write the request intputstream to a file. The problem is definitely on the Android side, which still causes the server to throw the "Stream ended unexpectedly" error.

Comment: I figured out the problem I was having. The solution I ended up using is almost exactly like the one I found here: http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/.

The real problem was that I wasn't correctly including the byte array of the image in the fileBody part of the request. Once I put the byte[ ] in there, things went much more smoothly.

Thanks for the suggestions on debugging, etc.

Comment: Raggedtoad, can you please put your comment in the answer and check it. It would be nicer for someone visiting your question, to know that it is answered (sometimes we miss the comments). thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the constructor :

```
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

The default is using mode STRICT and this may be the problem.

Comment: Already tried that one. Didn't make a difference for me. I still get this `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly`